# Dependency injection vs. creation when common constants are involved

Tags: javascript, oop, dependency-injection

Normally I opt for DI when an object consumes an instance of another object, but I'm hoping to get some insight on a case I ran into where the consuming object and the dependency share common instance constants.

- `Foo` is a façade class, that exposes `barMethod` from a `Bar` instance. `Foo` also exposes `buzzMethod` from a `Buzz` instance.
- Both `Bar` and `Buzz` are passed a root `key` for storing data in a `StorageArea`. They prepend that `key` to their subcomponents to identify them, so `barKey.A`, `barKey.B` etc.
- Different `Foo`s will be instantiated, each with their own `barMethod` and `buzzMethod`.
- I want to give each `Foo` its own `key` which I prepend to the keys for `Bar` and `Buzz`

Currently when I define my `Foo` class, I inject the two methods.

```js
class Bar {
  constructor(key, barData) {
    registerStorage(key)
    this.data = barData;
  }
  barMethod() {}
}

class Buzz {
  constructor(key, buzzData) {
    registerStorage(key);
    this.data = buzzData;
  } 
  buzzMethod() {}
}

class Foo {
  constructor(barMethod, buzzMethod) {
    this.barMethod = barMethod;
    this.buzzMethod = buzzMethod;
  }
}
```

##### Current Implementation: Factory

To facilitate the common key as well as other inner creation logic, I made a `fooFactory` which also accepts **the data needed to instantiate a `Bar` and `Buzz`**

```js
function fooFactory(key, barData, buzzData) {
  const bar = new Bar(key + 'bar', barData)
  const buzz = new Buzz(key + 'buzz', buzzData)
  return new Foo(bar.barMethod, buzz.buzzMethod)
}
```

##### Testing Workaround: Factory also returns inner instances

The issue that prompted this question was **testing**. I can still test `barMethod` and `buzzMethod`, but it's difficult to access and mock parts of the instances that expose those methods. My workaround was to also return them.

```js
function fooFactory(key, barData, buzzData) {
  const bar = new Bar(key + 'bar', barData);
  const buzz = new Buzz(key + 'buzz', buzzData);
  const foo = new Foo(bar.barMethod, buzz.buzzMethod);
  return {bar, buzz, foo}
}
```

In a way, one can claim that I don't need to test `bar` and `buzz` since they should be inconsequential or tested elsewhere. I can just test `foo.barMethod` and `foo.buzzMethod` in this context.

##### Question

I can't claim to know what's best in this specific case. I would appreciate insight or experiences on how this could be approaches in a better way, or if the current approach is good enough.

Comment: You might not like this comment, but in Javascript Composition solves a lot of your issues automatically.   I very rarely if ever now use classes, as functions / scope / closures pretty much do everything classes can but better.